# EJB3 Query + in clause

Tags: java, oracle, hibernate, ejb-3.0, ora-01722

I need to use an IN clause like the following SQL

```
SELECT * FROM tableA WHERE colA in (1, 2,3)
```

How can i do this in EJBQL?

i've tryed the following, which obviously failed:

```
SELECT tab FROM tableA tab WHERE tab.colA in (:colValues)
```

then in java i did

```
query.setParameter("colValues","1,2,3")
```

that gives me the following exception

```
org.apache.openjpa.lib.jdbc.ReportingSQLException: ORA-01722: invalid number
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is when you use `:parameter_name` in an sql fragment and then call `query. setParamter("parameter_name", values)` it is expected that `values` should be some sort of `collection`. Try this.

```
List<Integer> values = new ArrayList<Integer>();
values.add(1);
values.add(2);
values.add(3);

query.setParameter("colValues", values);
```

Answer (score 1):

It's been a long while since I've done EJBQL, but this should work:

```
  SELECT OBJECT(t)
       FROM Tab AS t
       WHERE t.colA IN (:colValues)
```

Also, you may need to set colValues as an array of numbers rather than a string